# video.js not working with IE9 and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-9, video.js

I use this plugin since a while.
But now i noticed it doesnt work anymore on IE9 and Chrome. Even on the offcial home page http://videojs.com/
It seems load the only 2 first seconds and then my web browser crashs.

Does somebody knows how to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome here though...

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. I'm using video.js now in Chrome (both on their site and my local machine) and it works fine. I'd wager this is something like a browser plugin that is conflicting with playback.

Comment: One small thing.. in my FF and IE the playbutton is not centered, shouldn't it be?